# Django Crispy forms input out of order

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-crispy-forms

I am building some forms using django-crispy_forms, I need them to be in the some specific order (specifically the order I stablished on the fields inside *forms.py*).

**forms.py:**

```
class RegistroRelatorio(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = RelatorioVendas

       fields = {"razao_social","codigo_interno","nome_fantasia","endereco","bairro","uf","telefones","cnpj","fundacao",
              "negocios","cidades_negocios","c1_nome","c1_whats","c1_email","c1_cargo","c1_comunicacao","c1_preferencia"}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import RelatorioVendas
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import RegistroRelatorio

# Create your views here.
def novo_relatorio(request):

form = RegistroRelatorio(request.POST or None)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponse('Ok...')

return render(request,'river/novo_relatorio.html',{'form':form})
```

**html:**

```
{% extends 'river/base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

        <h3>Novo Relatorio</h3>
        <form method="post" >

            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form | crispy}}

            <button type="submit">Ok</button>
        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I tried to use *label_order* inside this class, it worked, but when I use the **crispy form** it stops working...

I even tried to use the **Layout** method from the crispy library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 'list' instead of a 'set' for the `fields` in **forms.py**:

```
class RegistroRelatorio(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RelatorioVendas

        fields = ["razao_social", "codigo_interno", "nome_fantasia", "endereco", "bairro", "uf", "telefones", "cnpj",
                  "fundacao", "negocios", "cidades_negocios", "c1_nome", "c1_whats", "c1_email", "c1_cargo",
                  "c1_comunicacao", "c1_preferencia"]
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> A set is an ***unordered*** collection with no duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems here for crispy to render fields in the order that you provided. Show your html and views.